# Making a webpage stretch (or shrink) according to screen/window/device size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Here is my webpage:

[image]

Is it possible to stretch (or shrink) it according to the screen/window/device size? I want to avoid scrolling at all costs.

I am not concerned about the weird appearance of the page due to excessive stretching or shrinking.

I know it is stupid but I want it to look like an app rather than a webpage. Every element should remain at its place. It needs to be more like when you "stretch to fit" your wallpaper.

Comment: Should have thought about it while working on the CSS in the beginning...

Comment: You can use `$('body').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px', height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });` hide overflow in CSS then set some media queries to make it resposive.

Comment: You can use CSS Media Queries to control the display of the elements on the page based on screen size. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: You will need to show code and what you have tried so far to get any answers of good value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have three options for you.

1. You can go for a responsive design. Bootstrap will be more preferable.
2. Set an minimum size for viewport.`<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200px, maximum-scale=1.0 ">`
3. jQuery device width

   `var widnow_wth = $( window ).width();
   $(".wrapper").css('min-width',widnow_wth);`

Answer (score 1):

Add these two CSS styles into your div and it should work.

```
width: 80%;
height: 50%;
```

You can also refer to these websites for more information.

1. http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-1-column-full-page-pixels.htm
2. http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2171-adjusting-your-websites-to-fit-all-types-of-resolution